# Startscreen in iPad shows 2 splash-screens

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I have the problem that starting my app on iPad shows me 2 splash-screens. First one is correct iPad-splash. Second seems to be the splash of iPhone app (replaces the first one after about 500ms).

The devices-option in build settings is set to "universal".

Filenames for the images are:

- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Portrait~ipad.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default.png
  (in that order, not sure if that matters)

has anyone an idea why this happens?

Thx in advance. 
max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a Default~ipad.png file to your project for a iPad specific splash. The Default.png is meant for iPhone. For more info, see also the good blog entry [Icons and launch images for iPhone and iPad apps](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840).